# Can Malicious Programs make an ssd run out of read and write cycles?

Tags: ssd, malware, read-write

Just curious...
As I have heard that SSDs have a limited amount of read and write cycles, is it possible for a malicious program to cause rapid reads and writes to the SSD and cause a burnout rendering the SSD useless? Are there any protective measures for it? Tried to search the web but didn't find anything useful ...

Comment: While a possibility you have to ask yourself if this is likely. Most malware *wants* something from you, typically either money or valuable information. Simply destroying your data gets them nothing while encrypting it (even if unrecoverable) leaves open the possibility of recervery and extortion of money. Simply damaging something is the acta of a vandal, not someone with the skill to exploit a vulnerability and get far enough into the system to perform the tasks you are talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reads on an SSD are unlimited, writes are though. Once a block wears out, it goes read only.

If a (malicious) program is allowed to write to disk (create files, for example), then yes, it could try to exhaust SSD writes.

It's not a likely attack, though. Most modern malware campaigns aim at making profit (ransomware) or using computational resources of infected device (botnets). Making others' SSDs read only is rather pointless.

Comment: But is there any way to prevent this? It is very easy to create a little script that creates a file and deletes it immediately (To not arouse any suspicion) , consuming up one write cycle and setting it in an infinite loop... Set it on a USB drive to automatically copy and run the program upon insertion and you have got a USB-DriveDestroyer... Imagine this at a school with one rouge kid...

Comment: @psycoxer USB autoexec has been disabled for 14 years now (since Vista). You can't really prevent apps from writing to disk, so all devices are susceptible to this theoretical attack. You could take the paranoia approach: physically remove all ports and run everything on a VM with ramdisk storage; it's not quite practical though ;)